# Difference between "java $SOME_ENV_VAR -jar application.jar" and "java -jar $SOME_ENV_VAR application.jar"

Tags: java

I want to ask what is the difference when passing arguments before and after the -jar option in java command.
Consider $SOME_ENV_VAR=-Dinstance=qa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the contents of `SOME_ENV_VAR`; assuming it contains a valid command line argument such as `-Xmx512m`, then the first case could expand to

```
java -Xmx512m -jar application.jar
```

Alternatively, it might be a different jar file. And then second case would expand to

```
java -jar somethingelse.jar application.jar
```

In which case the jre would pass the `String` "application.jar" in the `String[]` args in `main`. Next, you might wonder about

```
java -jar application.jar $SOME_ENV_VAR
```

in which case it's the contents of `SOME_ENV_VAR` that get passed in `String[]` args to `main`. Finally, you can always use

```
String some = System.getenv("SOME_ENV_VAR");
```

And read the variable in code while using

```
java -jar application.jar
```